# Modificar posición de texto de radio button en android

Tags: java, android

¿Cómo hago para modificar un `radio button` en donde el círculo este en la izquierda o derecha según como quiera?. Por defecto me aparece así.

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />
```

**Antes**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que quiero es ponerlo así

**Después**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o también así, como un `match_parent`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualizacion**

Acabo de solucionarlo de la siguiente manera.

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
    android:button="@null"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: Hola @Santiago Si ya lo solucionaste agrega una nueva respuesta y acéptala tu mismo en lugar de editar la pregunta

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz quizas fue fallo mio porque yo le puse una respuesta, y el en lo comentario me dijo que le funciono pero hizo algunos cambios, y me los puso el los comentario, y como no se podian leer bien, le dije que lo podia poner como update para que otros que busquen lo mismo quizas con el codigo exacto le sea mas facil de entender, pero casi que solo son dos o tres lieneas son las que tienes que usar, pero yo para que lo entendiera mejor le puese un ejemplo un poco al azar en mi respuesta Saludos

Comment: @Santiago quizas el error fue mio a decirte que lo podias poner como update por si a alguien mas tiene el mismo error quizas al ver tu codigo exacto le sea mas facil de leer, en ese momento no pense que podria enterpretarse de otra manera, como una respuesta u otra cosa, tu eres libre lo pudes dejar, lo puedes borrar, lo puedes poner como respuesta, si bien es cierto que cuando alguien te dice una respuesta, no es lo normal ponerla como update, con los cambios que hicistes pero fue lo que se me ocurrio al ver que tu comentario en mi respuesta que casi no se leia bien al ser codigo sin formato

Comment: @Satiago Saludos

Comment: ok lo entiendo ahora estoy camino a casa y no puedo editar nada, soy nuevo, así que veré con mas detalle la guía.

Answer (score 3):

Usted puede intentar con lo siguiente:

- `android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"`
- `android:gravity="right"`

Puede quedarle algo asi:

```
      <RadioButton 
         android:layout_width      ="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height     ="wrap_content"
         android:text              ="New RadioButton"
         android:id                ="@+id/radioButton"
         android:layout_below      ="@+id/textViewOtro"
         android:layout_alignStart ="@+id/textViewOtro"
         android:button            ="@null"
         android:drawableRight     ="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
         android:layout_marginTop  ="50dp"
         android:background        ="@color/white"
         android:drawablePadding   ="30dp"
         android:textSize          ="25dip"/>
```

Comment: le agregue una propiedad `android:button="@null"` y le quite algunas como el gravity para que alineara y quedo bien ahora solo faltaría darle estilo.

Comment: me alegro que te funcionara, si solo fue un ejemplo basandome en el tuyo de como podria quedar, algunas quizas sean algo extrañas pero era para dar algo de contexto con un ejemplo. Saludos

Comment: @Santiago si quieres puedes poner tu nuevo codigo debajo de la pregunta diciendo como lo solucionates y como te quedo, añades update y pones el codigo diciendo que ahora si te funciona quizas ayude mejor a otros Saludos

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz el caso es que yo le dije unas cosas y el me puso el codigo con los cambios y me comento los cambios yo le explique mas o menos lo que habras leido, por eso le sugeri que pusiera el update quizas ayude mejor a otros. Saludos

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz no creo que te estas confundiendo la respuesta es esta, solo que el me dijo que hizo algunos cambio de eso, lo que habras leido. Saludos